# total data in a SQL table

Tags: sql

If I have 2 rows and 5 columns in a table, and when I run the a SQL query  I should get output as 10 as no of cells in a table. Please help me with a query for the same.

Second question: query to find number of data in a row.I require two types of queries, first : Query should exclude blank values, Null values and secondquery should include  only null values .
eg. a table had 10 row and 5 columns.  In first row data is present in all the five columns, Thus I will get count as 5 for row 1. In 2nd row, data is present in only 4 columns and last column has no data ie it is blank.Thus it will give count as 4. similarly assume if row 3 has data in 4 columns but Null value in any of the column it should give count as 4.

Please help me

Comment: You managed to write not one but two "please do my work for me" question in one question. And you tagged it with 2 tags that should no longer be used. Missings tags are the ones that describe which database you are using. Please show some effort and ask a clear, concise question.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

Number of total "cells" is easy:

```
select count(*) * 5 from T; /* no way to count the columns dynamically */
```

The others aren't much harder:

```
select
    case when col1 is not null then 1 else 0 end +
    case when col2 is not null then 1 else 0 end + ... as NonNulls
    case when col1 <> '' then 1 else 0 end +
    case when col2 <> '' then 1 else 0 end + ... as NonNullNonEmpty
from T
```

I believe you wanted that row by row rather than aggregated across the entire table. Wrap those in a `sum()` otherwise.

You'll have to change the queries if the number of columns were to change for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the total no. of column:

select count(*) from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns where TABLE_NAME = 'YourTableName';

And this is you complete solution of you question:

select count(*) * (select count(*) from 
INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns where TABLE_NAME = 'youtablename') from 'yourtablename';